# Scrolling for a readonly text area not working in a form

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a form where users can enter their data. Once the form is submitted the form becomes read-only for users. The data that is entered in the below field needs to be scrollable. But the scroll is not enabled.

Please help me figure out why the data in the above text area is not scrollable.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-3 control-label col-lg-3">Additional information <sup>*</sup></div>
    <div class="col-lg-6" style="overflow:auto;">
            <textarea style="overflow:auto;" class="form-control" name="additional-info" placeholder="Enter Additonal info">{{data}}</textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please make a fiddle? `textarea` is perfectly scrollable as far as I can see. https://jsfiddle.net/f1pc3n7w/

Comment: I don't know but for some reason it's not working for me

Comment: You can define the row attributes, so if the text will take more space the scroll will automatically set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a scroll, I made the whole text area visible by using the below code.

```
$('textarea').each(function() {
        $(this).height($(this).prop('scrollHeight'));
    });
```